# How can I remove arrows from ggbiplot of PCA in R that are not significant?

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

So, I am attempting to create a `ggbiplot` of a PCA of prey order in the diet of diurnal and nocturnal raptors, but the problem is that the `ggbiplot` function automatically creates arrows for each order. There are only about 8 orders that are significant for my research (i.e., have a value in PC1 and PC2 that is greater than or equal to 0.1).

This is what the `ggbiplot` looks like right now:

[image]

I've also been able to successfully remove all of the arrows using the `var.axes = FALSE` function to get this plot:

[image]

But the problem is that from either plot, I'm not sure how to either remove only a portion of the arrows so that I can just keep the 8 that I need, or add those 8 back to the plot from scratch after I remove all of the arrows.

Edit: I want the PC values for all 38 orders to still be factored into the plot, I just want to remove the unnecessary arrows until there are just 8 left.

Reproducible Example:

```
#load iris data
iris$Species = NULL # (to run the PCA)
iris_pca = prcomp(iris)
ggbiplot(iris_pca) + theme_classic()
```

So, let's say I don't want to include the arrows for Sepal.Width or Petal.Width. How would I remove those and keep the other two?

Comment: From a reading of the documentation, I would provide a vector supplying the 8 components to the `ggbiplot(df, choices = )` argument. You might be able to do this with a logical vector such as `choices = c(pc >= 1)` If you supply some data and the code you are using as a minimal example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) answers might be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, bob1. But would that then only plot the 8 orders I'm interested in and nothing else? I should've clarified in my question, I want to have the information for all of the orders being graphed into the ggbiplot, I just want to remove all of the other arrows until there are 8 arrows total (instead of an arrow for each order, like it's automatically outputting).

Comment: It is probably correct that it will only plot the 8 orders. I am not familiar with the package at all, but you may be able to plot with the 8 selected, then overlay with all by using another call to `ggbiplot`. Otherwise, some post-processing  to remove the arrows using inkscape or similar may be an idea.

Comment: MrFlick, just added a very simple reproducible example. My only question has to do with removing some arrows from the ggbiplot and keeping others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot/blob/master/R/ggbiplot.r), it doesn't look like you can. There is a cludge, shown below, where you alter the resulting `ggplot2` object.

```r
# Load library
library(ggbiplot)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: plyr
#> Loading required package: scales
#> Loading required package: grid

# Remove species
iris$Species <- NULL

# Perform PCA
iris_pca <-  prcomp(iris) 

# Create ggbiplot
g <- ggbiplot(iris_pca) + theme_classic()

# Before plot
plot(g)
```

[image]

```r
# Get ggplot2 object
g <- ggplot_build(g)

# Remove unwanted arrows & labels, say, Petal.Length Petal.Width
g$data[[1]] <- g$data[[1]][-(3:4), ]
g$data[[3]] <- g$data[[3]][-(3:4), ]

# Repackage & plot
plot(ggplot_gtable(g))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>